# DLR - Why isn't debug information showing up in my stacktrace?

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0

First, I've read [Making a CLR/.NET Language Debuggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357420/making-a-clr-net-language-debuggable/4384032#4384032), but am still having trouble implementing this.

I've written a toy language that works by generating a Linq Expression, then calling LambdaExpression#CompileToMethod. Most of these expressions have debug information attached like so:

```
//SmithExpression#InsertDebugInfo
Expression InsertDebugInfo(Expression expression, DebugInfo debugInfo) {
    var column = 1;
    var debugExpr = Expression.DebugInfo(debugInfo.SymbolDocumentInfo
                 ,Info.LineNumber, column, Info.LineNumber, column + 1);
    return Expression.Block(debugExpr, expression);
}
```

A DebugInfo looks like this:

```
public class DebugInfo {
    /* arbitrary value from http://www.famkruithof.net/uuid/uuidgen */
    public static Guid SmithGuid = new Guid("83c65910-8376-11e2-9e96-0800200c9a66");

    public readonly SymbolDocumentInfo SymbolDocumentInfo;
    public readonly DebugInfoGenerator DebugPdbGenerator;

    public DebugInfo(String name) {
        SymbolDocumentInfo = Expression.SymbolDocument(name, SmithGuid);
        DebugPdbGenerator = DebugInfoGenerator.CreatePdbGenerator();
    }
}
```

The whole thing is comipled like so (you can ignore the part about inits):

```
public static Action CompileSmithExpression(SmithExpression sexpression
           ,DebugInfo debugInfo, Parameter moduleParameter, Expando module) {
    AssemblyName assemblyName = 
        new AssemblyName(
             "RuntimeHelpers.CompileToSmithExpression helper assembly"
          );
    AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder =
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
          assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave
        );

    ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder
             .DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName.Name, "onlyModule.dll");

    var debugAttributes =
        DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default |
        DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations;

    ConstructorInfo constructor =
        typeof(DebuggableAttribute)
       .GetConstructor(new Type[] { 
           typeof(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes)
           }
        );
    var cab = new CustomAttributeBuilder(constructor, new object[] { debugAttributes });
    assemblyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(cab);
    moduleBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(cab);

    TypeBuilder typeBuilder = 
       moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyDynamicType", TypeAttributes.Public);

    //inits generates expressions that set 'constant' fields to their values.
    //the call also adds the 'constant' fields to the typeBuilder.
    //Must call ToArray() to make it run.
    var inits = FieldInits(sexpression, typeBuilder).ToArray();
    var ex = sexpression.ToExpression(debugInfo);
    var fullDlrExpression = Expression.Block(inits.Append(ex));

    var parameters = new ParameterExpression[] { moduleParameter.DlrParameter };
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(fullDlrExpression, parameters);

    /* Method will take the module as a parameter. */
    MethodBuilder meth = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        "MyMethod",
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static,
        typeof(void),
        new Type[] { typeof(Expando) } );

    lambda.CompileToMethod(meth, debugInfo.DebugPdbGenerator);

    Type madeType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

    return () => madeType.GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(null, new Object[] { module });
}
```

Running code gives the exception I want, but does not include the debug information that the expression had. I'd like it to say something like "<error_immediate, 1>".

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.MissingMemberException: Can't invoke member error of [] []
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.CallSite.Target (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,Smith.Expando) <IL 0x0004f, 0x00127>
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1<Smith.Expando, object> (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,Smith.Expando) <0x0040b>
at MyDynamicType.MyMethod (Smith.Expando) <IL 0x002bc, 0x00aaa>
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) <IL 0x00016, 0x00067>
etc...
```

My best guess is that the debug information actually is there, but that I'll have to do more work to get the stacktrace to show it. Any ideas?

Comment: Definitely more work, nothing simple.  http://dlr.codeplex.com/discussions/80850

Comment: "IronRuby maintains a mapping of IL offset to line number by providing a DebugInfoGenerator when compiling." This is exactly what I want to do, and every expression is already tagged with a DebugInfoExpression. If there's a way to go from an IL location to the DebugInfoExpression line number nearest it, then I can make a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is a nested exception. To print out the stack trace, take a look at the InnerException.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    while (ex != null) {
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        ex = ex.InnerException();
    }
}
```